# What module will show me all sql queries being run on the loaded page?

Tags: performance, database

My site is running slow and I suspect its a module, but not sure which one. Is there a module that can display all the sql queries being run on a loaded page? If there isn't maybe there is a command line tool that others use to monitor this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is better query log we can get from mysql log( more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log )

It shows real mysql queries with real values while the Devel's log shows placeholders.

So to get log of a page shutdown Mysql server, add the "log=" line in my.ini and restart the server then do the page load and then again stop the server and comment the log command.

Answer (score 14):

The [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) has a query log option, which when enabled will show every query that's been run for a request at the footer of the page.

You can enable it at admin/config/development/devel once the module's installed.

Comment: Seems this is no longer available in D8.

Comment: @Randell Now it's a sub-module called _Web Profiler_

Comment: The [Web Profiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/webprofiler) project page says the module has been merged with the *Devel* module since November 9, 2015.