# `drush cc all` takes (very) long time

Tags: caching

I'm running `drush` in order to clear all cache and it's taking long time (see below)

```
# time drush -d -r XXX -l XXX cc all
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 3.79 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0 sec, 3.99 MB]    [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-0-5ce9353199b62938f8d58e512601a610 [0.01 sec, 3.99 MB]                                                                                                                                            [debug]
Cache SET cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-0-5ce9353199b62938f8d58e512601a610 [0.03 sec, 4.01 MB]                                                                                                                                             [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.07 sec, 9.18 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.1 sec, 9.19 MB]                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.28 root directory at XXX [0.11 sec, 10.12 MB]                                                                                                                                              [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.11 sec, 10.13 MB]                                                                                                                                                      [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site XXX at sites/XXX [0.11 sec, 10.13 MB]                                                                                                                                                     [notice]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-install_profile-35170820d4d9fdf191f55e65e9f70975 [0.11 sec, 10.13 MB]                                                                                                                                          [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-2-5332f1db3bd7aa8d7d36192c27d8393d [0.12 sec, 10.13 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
Cache SET cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-2-5332f1db3bd7aa8d7d36192c27d8393d [0.19 sec, 10.14 MB]                                                                                                                                            [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.19 sec, 10.13 MB]                                                                                                                                             [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.2 sec, 10.17 MB]                                                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.2 sec, 10.18 MB]                                                                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.21 sec, 10.54 MB]                                                                                                                                                      [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-install_profile-35170820d4d9fdf191f55e65e9f70975 [0.49 sec, 56.72 MB]                                                                                                                                          [debug]
Cache SET cid: 6.2.0-install_profile-35170820d4d9fdf191f55e65e9f70975 [0.49 sec, 56.72 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-5-dfdf4a938767e55b12ec136058a7809c [0.49 sec, 56.78 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
Cache SET cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-5-dfdf4a938767e55b12ec136058a7809c [0.56 sec, 56.79 MB]                                                                                                                                            [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.57 sec, 57.26 MB]                                                                                                                                                     [bootstrap]
Successfully logged into Drupal as Anonymous (uid=0) [0.57 sec, 57.26 MB]                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Found command: cache-clear (commandfile=cache) [0.57 sec, 57.26 MB]                                                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Calling hook drush_cache_command_clear [0.67 sec, 57.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                                          [debug]
Calling drush_cache_clear_both() [0.67 sec, 57.71 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                [debug]

Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.44 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_ct_milestone_sections apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.44 MB]                                                                                                                                         [notice]
Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.44 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_ct_section_content apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.44 MB]                                                                                                                                            [notice]
Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.45 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_event_format apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.45 MB]                                                                                                                                                  [notice]
Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.45 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_is_secure apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.45 MB]                                                                                                                                                     [notice]
Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.46 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_magnified_alt_url apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.46 MB]                                                                                                                                             [notice]
Undefined index: facet_block_callback apachesolr.module:1716 [108.74 sec, 133.46 MB]                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Undefined index: field_related_contracts apachesolr.module:1719 [108.74 sec, 133.46 MB]                                                                                                                                             [notice]
'all' cache was cleared. [111.38 sec, 135.4 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                  [success]
Returned from hook drush_cache_command_clear [111.38 sec, 135.4 MB]                                                                                                                                                                  [debug]
Command dispatch complete [111.38 sec, 135.37 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   111.187    1      111186.8
Peak memory usage was 147.69 MB [111.38 sec, 135.36 MB]                                                                                                                                                                             [memory]

real    1m51.720s
user    0m7.889s
sys 0m1.085s
#
```

it doesn't seems like it's a memory issue as following:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo | head -1
MemTotal:        5991076 kB
# grep memory_limit /etc/php.ini 
memory_limit = -1
#
```

*AND* I have `apc` and `memcache` enabled

`mysqld` resides on another dedicated (physical) host

db server's:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo | head -1
MemTotal:        9027592 kB
#
```

from using `mysqltunner.pl`, my InnoDB data size is about ~50%-75% from `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

What else can I do in order to troubleshoot it?

Comment: @Clive, application itself seems to be a lot more responsive then older environment due to `APC` & `memcache` yet only `drush cc all` giving me issue, I can't really pin point it to server side either as everything seems to be working fine otherwise. BTW @MPD is disagreeing w/ Greg on that other question.

Comment: Yeah I only saw that answer just now. How good's your network/addressing, is the MySQL server close by physically and logically? That, plus your php-cli -> mysql connection, would be where I'd start looking for problems. I'll re-open this since you've added a lot more information than the other question now, just be aware that others might still consider it a duplicate and vote to close it as such. The two questions might eventually be merged too if they end up being similar enough but with answers that can cover both

Comment: Similar thread: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101726/drush-cc-all-takes-too-long-what-is-wrong-and-what-can-i-do/101732?noredirect=1#comment120024_101732

Comment: @geekgirlweb `max_execution_time` is set to `0` and my `php_memory_limit` is set to `-1`. btw it's not like process interrupts in the middle w/ error (not enough time or exceed memory limit) so ...